# PHP_CodeBrowser directory settings for more than one directory

Tags: ant, command-line-interface, jenkins, php-codebrowser

I have project structure like:

- application
- tests
- docs
- library

  - Zend
  - My_Lib

I setup my JenkinsCLI to make PHP_Code_Sniffer analysis and so on application and library/My_Lib. And now I need setup PHP_CodeBrowser to browse applivation and library/My_Lib too. But only this two I dont want to setup PHP_CodeBrowser to browse all files in project.

Is it possible and any clue how to do it?

My PHP_CodeBrowser ant task.

```
<target name="phpcb"
     description="Aggregate tool output with PHP_CodeBrowser">
    <exec executable="phpcb">
        <arg line="--log    ${basedir}/build/logs
          --source ${source}
          --output ${basedir}/build/code-browser" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `phpcb --help`:

```
-s source, --source=source      Path to the project source
                                code. . . .
                                Can be given multiple times
```

So try

```
<target name="phpcb"
     description="Aggregate tool output with PHP_CodeBrowser">
    <exec executable="phpcb">
        <arg line="--log    ${basedir}/build/logs
          --source ${source}/application
          --source ${source}/library/My_Lib
          --output ${basedir}/build/code-browser" />
    </exec>
</target>
```